# Docker: standard_init_linux.go:211

Tags: docker

I try to run python script with docker on windows pro in PowerShell.

When I run:

```
docker run -it --name mypython -v ${PWD}/myfirst:/app python /app/myfirst.py
```

I am getting an error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

myfirst.py includes only a print statement:

```
print('Python in Containers!')
```

In same time, the following pieces of code work fine:

```
docker run -it --name mypython -v ${PWD}/myfirst:/app python
>>> exec(open('/app/myfirst.py').read())
Python in Containers!
```

and

```
docker run -it --name mypython -v ${PWD}/myfirst:/app python /bin/bash
root@fc18bbcfb818 cd /app
root@fc18bbcfb818 python myfirst.py
Python in Containers!
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Which Docker image are you using? The official `python` image at https://hub.docker.com/_/python ?

Comment: @jakub Yes, official python image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python` Docker image has [the `CMD` `python3`](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/1b78ff417e41b6448d98d6dd6890a1f95b0ce4be/3.8/buster/Dockerfile#L98). This means that if you provide arguments after the image name, the `CMD` will be overwritten. So OP's example is equivalent to running `/app/myfirst.py` on the command line (note how this is different from `python /app/myfirst.py`). To fix this, use `python /app/myfirst.py`.

```
docker run -it --name mypython -v ${PWD}/myfirst:/app python python /app/myfirst.py
```